# WordPress на главной странице ошибка «too many redirects» после обновления

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

У клиента после обновления wordpress главная страница не открывается, выводит ошибку о циклической переадресации. Такая ошибка только на главной странице, все другие страницы, категории, записи - работают отлично.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если в настройках сайта ставлю, чтобы на главной странице выводились последние записи, а не статическая страница - все работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот код моего htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Список того, что я уже делал и что не помогло:

- Отключал все плагины, обновлял их.
- Пересохранял и менял настройкиЧПУ
- Создавал новую страницу и ставил ее в качестве главной
- Включал вывод ошибок
- Тему менял на стандартную
- flush_rewrite_rules() тоже не спасает

Плагинов кеширования нет, так что дело не в плагинах. В чем же может быть проблема и как решить этот вопрос? Спасибо за помощь!

Забыл сказать, домен кириллический...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в wp-config попробуйте добавить

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://site.ru');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://site.ru');
```

И еще есть подозрение что у вас стоит связка Apache + nginx

Answer (score 1):

Есть более эффективный способ. Точнее более универсальный ))

Вставить в wp-config.php строки

define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');

define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');

Ни чего прописывать не надо, получаете от текущего сервера.
Мне помогло ))
Удачи.